# What is the need of passing additional arguments to browserify's module constructor?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, browserify

I am just checking how `browserify` creates a bundle code. [prelude.js](https://github.com/browserify/browser-pack/blob/01d39894f7168983f66200e727cdaadf881cd39d/prelude.js) contains the IIFE that is executed with arguments of the format:

```
({
    id_one: [function(require, module, exports) {
        // Module Code
    }, {
        dependency_one: id_two,
        dependency_two: id_three
    }],

}, {}, [entryid])
```

However, I couldn't understand why do we need to pass these four extra arguments [outer, modules, cache, entry](https://github.com/browserify/browser-pack/blob/01d39894f7168983f66200e727cdaadf881cd39d/prelude.js#L36) to the function that is wrapping the module code? The signature of the function that it executes is of the format `require`, `module`, `exports` as shown in the below example. I tried without this and it works as well.

An example is:

```
// modules are defined as an array
// [ module function, map of requireuires ]
//
// map of requireuires is short require name -> numeric require
//
// anything defined in a previous bundle is accessed via the
// orig method which is the requireuire for previous bundles

(function outer(modules, cache, entry) {
    // Save the require from previous bundle to this closure if any
    var previousRequire = typeof require === "function" && require;

    function newRequire(name, jumped) {
        if (!cache[name]) {
            if (!modules[name]) {
                // If we cannot find the module within our internal map or
                // cache, jump to the current global require ie. the last bundle
                // that was added to the page.
                var currentRequire = typeof require == "function" && require;
                if (!jumped && currentRequire) {
                    return currentRequire(name, true);
                }

                // If there are other bundles on this page the require from the
                // previous one is saved to 'previousRequire'. Repeat this as
                // many times as there are bundles until the module is found or
                // we exhaust the require chain.
                if (previousRequire) {
                    return previousRequire(name, true);
                }
                var err = new Error('Cannot find module \'' + name + '\'');
                err.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
                throw err;
            }
            var m = cache[name] = {exports:{}};
            modules[name][0].call(m.exports, function(x){
                var id = modules[name][1][x];
                return newRequire(id ? id : x);
            },m,m.exports,outer,modules,cache,entry);
        }
        return cache[name].exports;
    }
    for(var i=0;i<entry.length;i++) newRequire(entry[i]);

    // Override the current require with this new one
    return newRequire;
})({
    1: [function(require, module, exports) {
        modulea = require("./modulea.js");
        moduleb = require("./moduleb.js");

        logger = function() {
            console.log(modulea + modulea);
        };

        console.log("Main executed.")
    }, {
        "./modulea.js": 2,
        "./moduleb.js": 3
    }],
    2: [function(require, module, exports) {
        module.exports.name = "Module A";

    }, {}],
    3: [function(require, module, exports) {
        module.exports.name = "Module B";


    }, {}]
}, {}, [1]);
```